# What branch of maths helps develop an effective problem solving mindset

Tags: soft-question, problem-solving

I have started doing maths about 5 years ago , i didnt have a math science orientation , but i have developped a study program specially for elementary algebra and geometry as well as basic statistics but didnt go further toward things like functions and trigonometry.

So after pursuig that program i have started to get into it with good sucess specially on mathematical problems dealing with equations and geometry basically middle school stuff.

Now after all these years i am preparing  for my job as a production planner/programmer also known as methods agent ; And my goal is to enhance my problem solving mindset.

So witch maths (if not all maths ) helps greatly with this ?

Comment: Challenging mathematical problems, that you can solve with your knowledge and that invite you to acquire new knowledge, I think it would be a good option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I improve my problem solving/critical thinking skills and learn higher math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315374/how-can-i-improve-my-problem-solving-critical-thinking-skills-and-learn-higher-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the biggest take away from math for general problem solving is that large problems can be broken into smaller problems and solved one step at a time.

Or, equivalently, solutions can be broken down into small pieces that can be reused or modified to suit other problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proof course which is a bridge between the calculus sequence and abstract courses such as modern geometry or advanced calculus or higher algebra. If you take such a course or just study a textbook in that regards you will benefit greatly.

Comment: thanks sir profoundly.

Comment: i would like some courses in the range of intermediate level maths

Comment: If a pre-calculus  course is too easy for you you may take a calculus methods course which is sometimes called a business calculus. Otherwise a pre-calculus course may help.

Comment: Hi sir one last question . what would be a bridging course between intermediate algebra and higher algebra ?

Comment: College algebra is what you want.

Comment: hi again mr kermani  i want to know if i can communicate with you using some social media app ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: hi again. Sorry for the wait. what i mean is is there a way we can communicate apart from this website to explain to you my problem easily ? kindly badroddine

Comment: alright sir never mind