# Improving Problem Solving Skills

Tags: problem-solving

After recently getting into math and math problem solving, I took the AMC 10 (my first AMC exam) and got a rather low score.
I want to improve my problem-solving skills and perhaps double-degree in the future (music performance + math).
I am currently a freshman in high school taking Algebra II, reading the Art of Problem Solving: Volume 1, and occasionally practicing problems on the AoPS website and past AMC tests.
How should I go about improving my problems solving skills, and just math skills in general?

Comment: Do more contest problems (at your level). Read Art of Problem Solving Vol 1 and 2 and do the problems in them. Those books are great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Improve Mathematical Thinking and General Problem Solving Skills?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227048/how-to-improve-mathematical-thinking-and-general-problem-solving-skills)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into a book titled "The Top-Down Approach to Problem Solving", by Eduardo Corpeño (that's me), ISBN 979-8464073296. It's on amazon as paperback and ebook.

It's a guide for high school and college freshmen to learn how to solve any problem, regardless of its type. I hope you like it.